# Determine the values of a and n leading to the optimal curve fit

Tags: voltage, current

The current, I in mA, in a circuit is measured for various voltage values V in volts. If the law connecting I and V is I = aV^n, where a and n are constants, draw an appropriate graph and determine the values of a and n leading to the optimal curve fit for the following set of values.
[image]

Can anyone explain me how to solve this excercise?

The solution is as follows
[image]

Comment: Optimal in what way?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what you want to optimize about your curve fit, so you can't really answer this question. However it appears your instructors want to steer you toward one fairly common method.

You have the formula

$$I = aV^n$$

You can't use the usual linear regression technique to find the parameters \$a\$ and \$n\$ because this is not a linear formula.

But if you take the log of both sides you get

$$\ln I = n \ln{aV}= n\left(\ln a + \ln V \right)$$

By defining \$A = n\ln a\$ and \$B = n\$, you can then re-write this as

$$ \ln I = A + B \ln V $$

And you have something you can apply the usual linear regression method to.

Of course this solution won't be optimized for minimum mean squared error between \$I\$ and the estimated \$I\$, but for minimum mean squared error between \$\ln I\$ and the estimated \$\ln I\$.

**Note**: I have been sloppy about taking the logarithm of dimensional quantities (quantities with units) here. I'm basically treating \$I\$ as "current in milliamps", a dimensionless quantity, and \$V\$ as "voltage in volts", another dimensionless quantity. You could choose other scaling factors than 1 mA for current and 1 V for voltages, but you should end up with the same result in the end.

Comment: You are very astute to point out that a linear least squares fitting algorithm places different emphasis in its fitting process depending on value magnitudes (in talking about ln(I).) It's possible to develop a least-squares technique that is directly applied to the model equation using partial derivatives in the same way that one develops the linear least square fitting algorithm, but of course with a different algorithm in the end. And who knows? As you say, the OP hasn't said what's to be optimized. So maybe the smallest sum of the squared-errors isn't the goal?

Comment: @jonk if the goal is minimum error in the estimate of n, then this method is probably pretty good, though I don't know if it's absolutely optimal.

Comment: In practice, it's ***horrible***. I spent two decades as part of a team designing and building phosphor thermometry instrumentation. This ***depends*** upon exponential decays as the illegal triplet states in the crystal lattices gradually decay out after being charged up with a bright pulse of light. There is ***noise***, as you are well aware, which is part of each successive sample. If you take the ln() first and use a standard LSQ fit you will put way too much emphasis on the noisy tail. The result is poor measurement and no one buys the product. (I had to develop the math and algorithm.)

Comment: @jonk, isn't that a different problem? When you're fitting an exponential decay, the independent variable *t* is in the exponent (i.e. \$Ae^{-\alpha t}\$). In OP's problem, the independent variable is the base and the unknown is the whole exponent (\$AV^n\$). I have done some fitting on exponential decays and agree it's a very tricky problem (especially where you might have a 2nd decay process with a different time constant going on at the same time).

Comment: Regardless, your point was good about the LSQ fit regarding ln(I). Whether or not we agree why, doesn't matter. In the presence of noise and other effects perhaps, any non-linear function performed on the data prior to fitting, in order that an LSQ fit algorithm that was never designed for the circumstance can be used, will have "issues" to consider. I'd never consider "linearizing" data before using a standard LSQ fit routine without first proving, mathematically, that the approach is soundly reasoned *for the application*. I'll leave it at that.